# Right Align <p> in navbar Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align a paragraph element in my navbar. 
As suggested I am applying the **.navbar-right** class, but it has no effect.

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/tamojohawu/edit?html,output)

Comment: Just add text-right class to <p> element.

Comment: Does your paragraph tag need to be inside the `navbar-header` div or is the `navbar-header` div ultimately not important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use paragraph tag `<p></p>` and change margin to `margin: 0 10px 0 0;`

for Ex.

```
<p class="navbar-text navbar-right text-right paddingRight" style="margin: 0 10px 0 0;">Right Align Here</p>
```

**UPDATE:**
For different screen size you have **`@media`** label in your CSS files.
In your case, i see some in navebar.less and bootstrap.css
take a look at your `bootstrap.min.css` on `line 5`. you can see:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-header {
    float: left; // change this to right
}
```

**1st solution:**
Change float to right if you want this in all of your pages.

**2nd solution:**
Add this style as an inline css if you want this change just for that page you are working with.
For example:

```
<div class="navbar-header" style="float: right!important;">

   <p class="navbar-text navbar-right text-right paddingRight" style="margin: 0 10px 0 0;">Right Align Here</p>

</div>
```

Comment: I did try out your solution. For a smaller screen it works. As soon as the scrren size changes to large the <p> moves back to the left

Answer (score 0):

Just add text-right class to `<p>` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="text-right"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I am loosing the padding being offered by Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
  <p class="navbar-text">Right Align Here</p>
</div>
```